# Kernel of chain map in $\textbf{Ch}(\mathcal{A})$ with $\mathcal{A}$ an abelian category (Weibel 1.2.3)

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I’m reasonably new to Homological algebra and category theory. I’m working through Weibel and I’m getting stuck on exercise 1.2.3, and theorem 1.2.3.
If $\mathcal{A}$ is an abelian category I want to show that $\textbf{Ch}(\mathcal{A})$ is an abelian category.

$\textbf{My attempt}$.
If $f$ is a chain map in $\textbf{Ch}(\mathcal{A})$, I want to show that $f$ has a kernel and cokernel.

I’ve shown that in $\textbf{Ch}(R-\textbf{mod})$ the complexes $\{ker(f)\}$ is the kernel of $f$ similarly for its cokernel. But I am not sure how this works in the general case of chain complexes over an abelian category, when $ker(f)$ becomes a map.

I’ve tried…

$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
A_{n+1}    &                       & A_{n}      &  & A_{n-1}\\
\quad \downarrow_{ker(f_{n+1})} &    & \quad \downarrow_{ker(f_n)} &  & \quad \downarrow_{ker(f_{n-1})} \\
C_{n+1}    & \xrightarrow{d_{n+1}} &  C_n       & \xrightarrow{d_n} & C_{n-1}\\
\downarrow_{f_{n+1}} & & \downarrow_{f_{n}} & & \downarrow_{f_{n-1}} \\
D_{n+1}    & \xrightarrow{d_{n+1}} &  D_n       & \xrightarrow{d_n} & D_{n-1}
\end{array}
$$

And tried to see if these maps are what is required, but how can I define the sequence of $\{A_n\}$ to be a chain complex, do I put the zero map between each of them? And if so, how can I be sure then that $ker(f)$ is a chain map??

Given that I cant even show that kernels and cokernels exist I have very little hope of showing that every monic is the kernel of its cokernel etc...

Comment: What are the $A_n$'s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $$A_n\to C_n\to C_{n-1}\to D_{n-1}=A_n\to C_n\to D_n\to D_{n-1}=0,$$ a unique morphism $d_n\colon A_n\to A_{n-1}$ is induced from $A_n\to C_n\to C_{n-1}$. In general, the zero would not make the diagram commute.

Next,
$$\begin{align}A_{n+1}\to A_n\to A_{n-1}\to C_{n-1} &= A_{n+1}\to A_n\to C_n\to C_{n-1} \\ &=A_{n+1}\to C_{n+1}\to C_n\to C_{n-1} \\ &= 0,
\end{align}$$ hence already $A_{n+1}\to A_n\to A_{n-1}=0$. This makes $A_\bullet$ a chain complex.

The same type of (here, element-less) diagram chasing will help you show that $A_\bullet$ (together with $\ker f_\bullet$) has the universal property of a kernel; that the dual argument works for cokernels; and so on.

Comment: How did you arrive at your second sequence of equalities? In other words how do you know that the top row of squares in the OP's post commute?

Comment: @gen If you chase through the construction of the differentials in the complex $\ker f_*$, the commutativity of those squares falls out. They come from commutativity in the diagram for kernels in the original abelian category $\mathcal{A}$. I'm happy to add the details as an answer if anyone needs them.